# How to properly mix Superior Drummer 2.*

Tags: midi, mixing

How do you mix Superior Drummer drums?
Do you use built-in mixer, or you use 3d party plugins?

Answer (score 2):

I like to use my other plugins for compression and EQ with Superior Drummer. I tend to look at things like the SSL plugin and McDSP's set. They give me a lot more control over the compression and EQ which keeps me close to the way that I mix it live as well.

Answer (score 2):

I bounce the audio & use [this template in pro tools](http://www.protoolsitb.com/index.php?dispatch=products.view&product_id=10) (not free)

[image: template screenshot]

> **Description**
>
> Learn how to mix drums in Pro Tools in this session.  Comes with
> complete audio drum tracks.  Learn how to mix Kick, Snare, Hats, Toms,
> OH, Room, mono Room, parallel compression.
>
> Includes 2 sessions (same
> audio)
>
> Session 1: Mixed with Waves SSL, CLA-Signature, CLA-Classic
> compressors, McDSP AC2, TheGlue Compressor, and Waves Renaissance
> plugins.
>
> Session 2: Mixed with Digi EQ & Compressors that come with
> Pro Tools.